# How to read Docx Meta-filed in Python?

Tags: python-docx

I checked out Python-docx module, it appears you can only read document.core_properties.
What about other meta fields in header or footer?

Currently I had to dump all the text using doc2txt and then search.

Comment: What do you mean "in header or footer"?

Comment: For example, the docx file I got have several field names in footer: {DOCPROPERTY "DocTitle"},  {DOCPROPERTY "USerDocNo"}, {DOCPROPERTY ReviewDate }, these meta info were not part of core_properties except Title . I also tried to use section[0].header.paragraphs.text method, but the text cannot be extract.